# how to output all the loop results in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the same prefix, I want to output all the lm results. Here are simulate the data frame and the scripts.

```
test<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
dd <- subset(test, X10 != 0)

for(i in i:length(nrow(dd)-1)){
  x<- dd$X10
  y<- dd[, grep("X",names(dd[ ,-1]))]
  lm_name<- paste("lm", "_", i, sep="")
  lm_name<- lm(y[[i]]~x) 
  }
```

Hope someone could help. Thanks!

Comment: You can add `summary(lm_name)` before final curl inside the loop!

Comment: What is `plotname`? If it is `dd`, then `length(nrow(plotname)-1)` is 1. Also `dd$X10` is a vector with a constant value of 1 and the last statement in the loop overwrites the `lm_name` variable defined in the line just before it.

Comment: @dcarlson Sorry, I forgot to change the initial name.

Comment: @Duck Yeah, but my loop doesn't work, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should just assign the results of each loop iteration to something.

```
res.for <- c()
for(i in 1:(ncol(dd) - 1)) {
  x <- dd$X10
  y <- dd[, grep("X", names(dd[, -1]))]
  lm_name <- paste0("lm_", i)
  res.for[[i]] <- lm(y[[i]] ~ x)
  names(res.for)[i] <- lm_name
}

res.for[1:3]
# $lm_1
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = y[[i]] ~ x)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)            x  
#        0.4864           NA  
# 
# 
# $lm_2
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = y[[i]] ~ x)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)            x  
#        0.5136           NA  
# 
# 
# $lm_3
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = y[[i]] ~ x)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)            x  
#           0.5           NA
```

However, you could do this a ton easier using `lapply` and `reformulate`.

```
res <- setNames(lapply(names(dd)[-10], function(y) lm(reformulate("X10", y), dd)),
                paste0("lm_", seq_len(ncol(dd) - 1)))
res[1:3]
# $lm_1
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = reformulate("X10", y), data = dd)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          X10  
#        0.4864           NA  
# 
# 
# $lm_2
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = reformulate("X10", y), data = dd)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          X10  
#        0.5136           NA  
# 
# 
# $lm_3
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = reformulate("X10", y), data = dd)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          X10  
#           0.5           NA
```

```
coef1 <- function(x) coef(x)[1]
stopifnot(all.equal(sapply(res, coef1), sapply(res.for, coef1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

magic_for is a very nice package, well sutied for this. notice that your loop doesnt work, as per @dcarlson's comment so i replaced `1:length(nrow(plotname)-1)` with `1:length(nrow(test)-1)` for demonstration purposes EDIT changed to `1:length(nrow(dd)-1)` as per OP

```
library(magicfor)

test<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
dd <- subset(test, X10 != 0)

magic_for(print, silent=T, progress=T)

for(i in 1:length(nrow(dd)-1)){ # edited to match changes in OP's post
  x<- dd$X10
  y<- dd[, grep("X",names(dd[ ,-1]))]
  lm_name<- paste("lm", "_", i, sep="")
  lm_name<- lm(y[[i]]~x) 
  print(lm_name)
}

result<-magic_result_as_vector()
result
```

you can also access results as `magic_result()` or `magic_result_as_data_frame()` depending on specific needs

Comment: I'm not sure that `1:length(nrow(test)-1)` is correct either, `nrow()` returns a vector of length 1, so that's just iterating over `1:1`.

Comment: you are right, it was just done to make the data.frame work. i really didnt put any effort into the data frame itself and just did a quick fix to demonstrate the use of magic_for. you are deffinetly right about `nrow(test)` not being optimal. i just didn't think it was too relevant for the point i was making. - it was now also changed in the original question so i edited my answer correspondingly